# Docker image build failed, openjdk-8-jdk version not found

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a docker image but get the following error. The error first occurred after a complete new build, manually removing all docker images within the docker windows app.

```
=> [ 1/18] FROM docker.io/library/node@sha256:25516f3de85ebf588e29d81052495d2e1177b55cddbd7ddab2f5ff2c4496dd5e    0.0s
=> [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.2s
=> => transferring context: 23.72kB                                                                               0.2s
=> CACHED [ 2/18] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential bzip2 -y                                  0.0s
=> CACHED [ 3/18] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                   0.0s
=> CACHED [ 4/18] RUN echo 'deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' >  0.0s
=> ERROR [ 5/18] RUN set -x  && apt-get update  && apt-get install -y   openjdk-8-jdk="8u292-b10-0+deb9u1"   c  133.7s
> [ 5/18] RUN set -x   && apt-get update       && apt-get install -y           openjdk-8-jdk="8u292-b10-0+deb9u1"
ca-certificates-java="20161107~bpo8+1"  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
#8 0.539 + apt-get update
#8 1.131 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [121 kB]
#8 1.174 Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
#8 1.360 Get:3 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease [166 kB]
#8 1.493 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [51.9 kB]amd64 Packages [285 kB]
#8 1.709 Get:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [285 kB]
#8 1.906 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7907 kB]
#8 2.191 Err:3 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InReleasec key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD62469
#8 2.191   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
#8 131.6 Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [10.9 kB]
#8 132.8 Reading package lists...
#8 133.7 W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
#8 133.7 E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease' is not signed.

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c set -x      && apt-get update       && apt-get install -y           openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION"            ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION"    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit code: 100
ERROR: Service 'simulation-manager' failed to build : Build failed
```

Thinking that the missing signatures might be the problem, I added the following two rows to the dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010 8B48AD6246925553
RUN apt-get update
```

However, this produced the following error:

```
 => [ 1/20] FROM docker.io/library/node@sha256:25516f3de85ebf588e29d81052495d2e1177b55cddbd7ddab2f5ff2c4496dd5e                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                 0.1s
 => => transferring context: 26.90kB                                                                                              0.1s
 => CACHED [ 2/20] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential bzip2 -y                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/20] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/20] RUN echo 'deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sourc  0.0s
 => [ 5/20] RUN apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010 8B48AD6246925553                                 3.6s
 => [ 6/20] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                  143.6s
 => ERROR [ 7/20] RUN set -x  && apt-get update  && apt-get install -y   openjdk-8-jdk="8u292-b10-0+deb9u1"   ca-certificates-ja  5.4s

 > [ 7/20] RUN set -x   && apt-get update       && apt-get install -y           openjdk-8-jdk="8u292-b10-0+deb9u1"                    ca-certificates-java="20161107~bpo8+1"   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
#10 0.851 + apt-get update
#10 1.172 Hit:1 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease
#10 1.173 Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
#10 1.173 Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
#10 1.215 Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
#10 2.947 Reading package lists...
#10 3.856 + apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk=8u292-b10-0+deb9u1 ca-certificates-java=20161107~bpo8+1
#10 3.885 Reading package lists...
#10 5.072 Building dependency tree...
#10 5.273 Reading state information...
#10 5.418 E: Version '8u292-b10-0+deb9u1' for 'openjdk-8-jdk' was not found

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c set -x      && apt-get update       && apt-get install -y           openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION"           ca-certificates-java="$CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION"    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit code: 100
ERROR: Service 'simulation-manager' failed to build : Build failed
```

The version which was not found however, is the latest one following https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/openjdk-8 (and included in the dockerfile as "ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 8u292-b10-0+deb9u1").

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful, more than just the `docker build` logs.  In general you can't pin APT packages to extremely specific versions, since the Debian and Ubuntu repositories delete them pretty promptly once there's a newer build.

Comment: openjdk-8-jdk is only available in Debian Stretch (oldstable), but your base image uses Debian Buster. so you have to explicitly add the oldstable repos to your sources list:
`RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ oldstable/updates main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list`
`RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian oldstable main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @urfin78 This worked just perfectly and the image was built correctly! Thank you so much, if you want you can add it as an answer so I can "accept" it?

Comment: This will only work until Debian bullseye will be released (later this year) and buster will become the new `oldstable`. I don't know how long the debian stretch (which will then be oldoldstable) repositories will be online after that, so maybe the better solution would be to adapt to jdk11 or newer java version somehow.